# substituting special characters using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with the first field like this:

```
ENSGALG00000000189|ENSGALT00000000247|10|3979|4020
```

I want to get rid of the "|" sign and just have a space.

I have been trying this code but it doesn't work:

```
awk -F "|" '{gsub ("|", "")' file
```

I'd be very thankful if you could help me with this.Thanks

Comment: You are nearly there, you missed a final `}` and a `1` to print it out.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do

```
echo "ENSGALG00000000189|ENSGALT00000000247|10|3979|4020 " | awk -F\| '$1=$1' OFS=" "
ENSGALG00000000189 ENSGALT00000000247 10 3979 4020
```

Or some more robust

```
awk -F\| '{$1=$1}1' OFS=" "
```

These sets input Filed Separator to `|` and Output Separator to `"space"` `$1=$1` reconstruct the data using new separator.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr` instead of `awk`:

```
tr '|' ' ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub`:

```
$> echo "ENSGALG00000000189|ENSGALT00000000247|10|3979|4020" | awk '{ gsub (/\|/, " "); print }' 
ENSGALG00000000189 ENSGALT00000000247 10 3979 4020
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the pipe symbol -

```
$ cat file
ENSGALG00000000189|ENSGALT00000000247|10|3979|4020
```

Using **awk**

```
$ awk -F '|' '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}' file
ENSGALG00000000189 ENSGALT00000000247 10 3979 4020
```

Using **sed**

```
$ cat file | sed 's/|/ /g'
ENSGALG00000000189 ENSGALT00000000247 10 3979 4020
```

Comment: The `awk` solution is not good, since its only valid for a fixed set of elements.